# How to reset response in Wicket 1.5

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

In wicket 1.4 webResponse.reset() cleans buffer. But in wicket 1.5 there is a some kind of garbage left.

Response:

```
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
```

And then my valid json follows.

```
WebResponse webResponse = (WebResponse) cycle.getResponse();
webResponse.reset();

webResponse.setContentType("application/x-json; charset=utf-8"); //$NON-NLS-1$
Url url = RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().getBaseUrl();
webResponse.setHeader("Wicket-Ajax-BaseURL", url.toString()); //$NON-NLS-1$
webResponse.disableCaching();

// Write x-json content to the response.
String output = json.toString();

webResponse.write(output);
```

Comment: Also wicket 1.5 started to use HeaderBufferingWebResponse instead of BufferedWebResponse. And BufferedWebResponse implementation was completely changed.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It sounds to me like you should just use a Resource instead.